# CVXPY constraint with N variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, convex-optimization, cvxpy

Trying to figure out a way to write a constraint with N variable to use on [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org/) that fit this:

```
var1 + var2 + ... + varN = K # K is a constant
```

All variables objects are instantiated and are stored in a list.

```
[Variable, Variable, ...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write

```
   constraint = (sum([Variable, Variable, ...]) == K)
```

Then be sure to include that constraint in your problem.